# Linking error when trying "stack install yesod-bin"

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I would like to start developing for web using yesod framework.
But I can not install yesod.

I'm following the steps suggested:

```
stack new my-project yesod-sqlite
cd my-project
stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
```

But the "stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc" command gives me the following output:

```
clock-0.7.2: configure
clock-0.7.2: build
basement-0.0.4: configure
file-embed-0.0.10.1: download
hourglass-0.2.10: download
basement-0.0.4: build
file-embed-0.0.10.1: configure
file-embed-0.0.10.1: build
hourglass-0.2.10: configure
hourglass-0.2.10: build
file-embed-0.0.10.1: copy/register
hourglass-0.2.10: copy/register
Progress: 4/93
--  While building custom Setup.hs for package basement-0.0.4 using:
      /home/mbaroni/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.1.0_ghc-8.2.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/mbaroni/Computacao/prog/yesod-project/.stack-work/logs/basement-0.0.4.log

    Configuring basement-0.0.4...
    Preprocessing library for basement-0.0.4..
    /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_utils.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'vprintf' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
    command was: /usr/bin/gcc .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make.o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_utils.o -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Basement/Terminal/Size_hsc_make -fuse-ld=gold -fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector -fuse-ld=gold -L/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/base-4.10.1.0 -Wl,-R,/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/base-4.10.1.0 -L/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/integer-gmp-1.0.1.0 -Wl,-R,/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/integer-gmp-1.0.1.0 -lgmp -L/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1 -Wl,-R,/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/ghc-prim-0.5.1.1 -L/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/rts -Wl,-R,/home/mbaroni/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.2.2/lib/ghc-8.2.2/rts -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread
```

Any idea about what could be the cause of the problem would be greatly appreciated.

My environment:

```
stack --version                      
Version 1.6.1, Git revision f25811329bbc40b0c21053a8160c56f923e1201b (5435 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0

ghc --version                   
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2

uname -a
Linux mbaroni 4.12.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 15 06:36:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: what resolver do you use? - can you show us your `stack.yaml`

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out what was the problem and I was able to solve it in my environment.

#### Reason

It seems that GCC enabled PIE (Position Independent Executable) by default and stack (which uses GCC in the back) does not expect this, causing the reported problem at linking stage ([source](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2712#issuecomment-254085837)).

#### Solution

As suggested [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3540#issuecomment-341086100) the solution was to configure stack to pass gcc the right flags to correct this.

This is done editing the file "~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/settings" in my case.
I had to modify the configuration of 3 lines as follows:

```
 ...
 ("C compiler flags", "-fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector -fPIC"),
 ("C compiler link flags", "-no-pie -fuse-ld=gold"),
 ("C compiler supports -no-pie", "YES"),
 ...
```

Best.